# PHP Before during an If statement

Tags: loops, if-statement

I want call a BEFORE in PHP

my code so far:

```
<?php
$folder_path = $cdnurl . 'assets/' . $pid . '/';

// Loop from 2 to 5
for ($i = 2; i <= 6; $i++) {

if(@fopen($folder_path . $i . '/large.jpg',"r")){
?>

    <li><a id="<?php echo $i;?>" href="<?php echo $i;?>/large.jpg"><?php echo $i;?></a></li>

<?php } else {
break;
}
}?>
```

**EDIT**
I edited the code above as it is already nested with IF and ELSE. I want it to echo. something like

```
<ul>
<li>2</li>
<li>before</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a basic if():

```
for ($i = 2; $i <= 6; $i++) {
   if ($i < 3) {
      echo "before 3"
   } else {
      echo "<li> yada yada yada";
   }
}
```

Though, since you're starting your for loop at 2, this would only ever output "before 3" once, when i=2. So it'd be more efficient to do:

```
echo "before 3";
for ($i = 3; .......) {
    echo "<li>....";
}
```

instead and save yourself the useless if() check.

---

given your code sample update:

```
echo "<ul>";
for ($i = 2; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    if ($i == 3) {
        echo "<li>before</li>";
    }
    if (is_readable("{$folder_path}{$i}/large.jpg")) {
        echo <<<EOL
<li><a id="{$i}" href="{$i}/large.jpg">{$i}</a></li>
EOL;
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Note the use of [`is_readable()`](http://php.net/is_readable). It's easier to check for a file's existence/readability using that than trying open the file. As well, note the [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc) used to output the list element, rather than a regular echo.

Comment: thanks, I tried this but I have attached the correct code above as it is already nested in elements.

Comment: thanks man! I appreciate it. I always want to know what that was (HEREDOC) so basically it it like doing an echo with many lines?

Comment: pretty much. it acts like a multi-line double-quoted string, but without needing the quotes to be escaped. There's also "nowdocs", which are heredocs, but act like single-quoted string (so variables don't get interpolated).

Answer (score 0):

You can check `$i`, to find out at which position in the loop you currently are. On the first run, `$i` will be 0, the second one 1, etc. You can then use a simple `if`-statement to find out if you're under run #3. Using `break` you can "break out" of a loop.

```
for( $i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++ ) {
    if( $i < 3 ) {
        // Code to execute if $i < 3
    } else {
        // Code to execute if $i >= 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a check if $i is less than or equal to 3:

```
if ($i <=3){
  echo 'before #3';
}
```

If i understand your question correctly.